# Re-enable disabled submited form via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I use folowing code to disable multiple submits of form

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    return true;
});
```

but cant find a way to reenable submit

```
$('input[type=submit]').prop( "disabled", false );
```

above dont work, how to reenable submit

Comment: Your code is a submit handler, nested inside a submit handler, one returning false, the other true. It is the 'mobius-strip' of code. Maybe if you told us what your code is trying to do we would be able to help better.

Comment: `prop` as it suggests, is related to `properties`, not event handling.

Comment: my code disable submit after first one. I want in certain case to be able to submit form again without reloading page.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, it seems like a genuine question that a new user would make. Instead of down voting, you should edit the question to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).submit(function() { // double nested
      return false; 
      // this one stops the propagation and any other submit that submit event 
      // handler lower on the stack (i.e.: like the first one) won't work.
   });
});
```

This doesn't disable the form, when the form is submited, you are simply setting another event on top.

The reason why it seems disabled is because the second submit handler, has `return false`, which in it's turn stops the propagation of the event into the first submit.

You would be much better with a boolean:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
   if( !formActive ) { return; }
   ...
});
function disableForm() { formActive = false; }
function enableForm() { formActive = true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=submit]').removeProp("disabled");
```

This should work.